# Finding the general solution of $\cos4 \theta = \cos2 \theta $

Tags: trigonometry

> I have to find the general solution of this trigonometric equation
>   $$\cos4 \theta = \cos2 \theta $$

I solved in the following manner, but I got the wrong answer.

$$\begin{align}
\\\cos4 \theta &= \cos2 \theta \\
2\cos^2 2\theta -1&=\cos2 \theta \\
(\cos2 \theta-1)(2\cos2 \theta +1)&= 0
\end{align}$$

$$
\cos2 \theta= 1 \text{ or }-\frac 12 \\[12pt]
\theta = n\pi \text{ or }n\pi \pm \frac\pi3 
$$

Can anyone tell me what's I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\cos(4 \theta) = \cos(2 \theta) \implies 4 \theta = 2 \theta + 2 \pi k$ or $ 4 \theta = -2 \theta + 2 \pi k$, i.e. $ \theta = \pi k, \theta = \frac{\pi k }{3}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Remember that $cos(x) = cos(x+2\pi n)$ when n is an integer - (Edit - Someone already mentioned that)

Comment: @fGDu94 thanks for the solution, but I specifically wanted to know what's the error in my answer and why I'm getting a wrong one.

Comment: because $\cos(2\theta) = 1$ has the solution $2\theta = 2 \pi k$ for $k$ an integer, and $\cos(2\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$ has the solution $2\theta = 2 \frac{\pi}{3} k$ for $k$ an integer, $k$ not divisible by $3$.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your solution the values of $3\theta$ are $$3n\pi,(3n\pm1)\pi$$

Now using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$0=\cos2\theta-\cos4\theta=2\sin\theta\sin3\theta$$

So, it is sufficient to have $$\sin3\theta=0\implies3\theta=m\pi$$ where $m$ is an integer

Observe that $m$ can be represented by at least one of the forms $$3n,3n-1,3n+1$$

So, the two results actually coincide

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually the wrong answer, but you can express the general solution in other ways - in this case you can write it as $$\theta=\frac{n\pi}{3}$$

Comment: how will i obtain the values like $ \pi , 2 \pi $ ... when $$\theta = n\pi \text{ or }n\pi \pm \frac\pi3 $$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \cos2 \theta= 1 ,-\frac 12 $$

$$2\theta = 2n\pi,(2n-1)\pi \pm \frac\pi3$$

$$ \theta = n\pi,  (2n-1)\pi/2 \pm \frac\pi6 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it faster using congruences:
$$\cos 4\theta=\cos2\iff4\theta\equiv\pm2\theta\mod 2\pi\iff2\theta,6\theta\equiv 0\mod2\pi\iff\begin{cases}\theta\equiv 0\mod\pi,\\[1ex]\theta\equiv 0\mod\dfrac\pi 3.\end{cases}$$
Now observe the first set of solutions is contained in the first, so that the set of solutions is finally
$$\theta\equiv 0\mod \frac \pi3.$$